# Searchkick suggestions support for 3 chars words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-5, searchkick

I'm using searchkick suggestions on my rails app and everything is working fine except suggestions for 3 char words! when i type for example 'Eg' i'm expecting to to 'Egg' suggestion but this doesn't happen, my question is how to support this feature ?!

my code:

```
Product.search(
    params[:q],
    suggest: true,
    limit: 10
  ).suggestions
```

Answer (score 0):

The minimum length of words to be included by default is 4. You can change that by passing `min_word_length` into elastic. Please see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html#_other_term_suggest_options